# how to convert string format to date format in hive

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql, datetime-format

I've timestamp and date columns in my table. My date and timestamp columns are in string type. I need to convert it to DATE and TIMESTAMP format. But the format in my data is 2/4/2017 3:03. So when I convert it to TIMESTAMP datatype it gives NULL. What can we do to resolve this?

Here is my sample date& time column data.

```
2/3/2017 23:37
2/3/2017 23:37
2/3/2017 23:40
2/3/2017 23:50
2/3/2017 23:51
2/3/2017 23:53
2/3/2017 23:55
2/4/2017 0:08
2/4/2017 0:57
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your code of what you tried??

Comment: d/M/yyyy or M/d/yyyy?

Answer (score 1):

```
create table mytable (dt_tm string);

insert into mytable values
    ('2/3/2017 23:37')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:37')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:40')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:50')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:51')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:53')
   ,('2/3/2017 23:55')
   ,('2/4/2017 0:08' )
   ,('2/4/2017 0:57' )
;
```

---

```
select  dt_tm
       ,cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt_tm,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'),'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00') as timestamp)

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+----------------+---------------------+
| 2/3/2017 23:37 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:37 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:40 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:50 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:51 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:53 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:55 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/4/2017 0:08  | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/4/2017 0:57  | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:37 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:37 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:40 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:50 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:51 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:53 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/3/2017 23:55 | 2017-03-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/4/2017 0:08  | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
| 2/4/2017 0:57  | 2017-04-02 00:00:00 |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But I need to extract just the date from this field to find out the day wise productivity and change the data type of this field to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Change your post to reflect your real request.  I'll send you a solution in 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command

> unix_timestamp(dates, 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss')

might be it will resolved your problem. I don't have hive setup right now.